# WCF How to Increase buffer size in Metro Application(Client Side)

Tags: wcf, windows-8, wcf-binding

i get this Error :

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http: //localhost:4936/UserService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Inner Exception :
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Here is my Web.config ( Service Layer ):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DellenyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DellenyModel.csdl|res://*/DellenyModel.ssdl|res://*/DellenyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Delleny;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="DellenyModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DellenyModel.csdl|res://*/DellenyModel.ssdl|res://*/DellenyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Delleny;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicBinding"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="1500000"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000"
                 maxBufferSize="1500000">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Delleny.Services.UserService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding"
                  contract="Delleny.Model.IUserService" />
      </service>
      <service name="Delleny.Services.BCService">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding"
                  contract="Delleny.Model.IBCService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: The best way on to drill into the error would be to enable Tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service and see the exact reason on why you are getting that error. It might be due to the amount of data being sent or received by your service. Increase your readerQuotas on both client and server side

Comment: that's exactly the error .. how to increase the reader quota on Client side and server side ?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your binding element with something as shown below:

```
<binding name="BasicBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" maxBufferSize="2000000" transferMode="Streamed">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000" maxArrayLength="2000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000" />
</binding>
```

Comment: I added this code , but I still get the same error , Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the approx. size of data being sent/received by the service? Also consider increasing the maxItemsInObjectGraph in your serviceBehaviour. And if the size is more than than 4MB consider increasing your httpRunTime maxRequestLength